# Able to delete, but no confirmation

Tags: google-app-maker

I have question for Google App Maker.

I need a delete confirmation for every record on table. I already learn this url [Dynamically Bind Data source to app maker popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115362/dynamically-bind-data-source-to-app-maker-popup),  but It's not work with my case. What I did is :

a. On delete button, I set script :
    widget.datasource.deleteItem(widget.parent.datasource);

b. On Confirmation button, I put script :
    // GENERATED CODE: Add your action below.

```
if (typeof widget.root.properties.CallbackFn === 'function') {
widget.root.properties.CallbackFn();    
}
widget.root.visible = false;

app.closeDialog();
```

c. On Client Script, I put :

```
function deleteItem(datasource) {
var popup = app.popups.ConfirmationDialog;
var datasource2 = datasource;

popup.properties.CallbackFn = function() {
    datasource.deleteItem();
      };

popup.visible = true;
}
```

The result, I able to  delete record, but no confirmation. Tell me know, what wrong with my script. 
@markus-malessa

Comment: Your delete button on click needs to be deleteItem(widget.datasource). And of course your popup needs to have a dynamic property called CallbackFn.

Comment: Ok thanks @MarkusMalessa, it work. Finally I found dynamic property :)

Answer (score 0):

To show the deletion confirmation, I use a confirmation dialog popup. When I click "Yes", the application removes the current element from my data source with the code:

```
widget.datasource.deleteItem({success: successfullyDeleted()});
```

In "successfullyDeleted", I show a notification dialog that the item has been successfully deleted.